# android studio doesn't see sdk

Tags: android, android-studio

I today updated sdk as studio suggest,
after that in such code

```
import android.app.Fragment;

    public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {
```

it show `Fragment` in red, and show hint `Cannot resolve symbol 'Fragment'`,
but `Build->Make Project` without problem,
how can I fix this issue?

`.AndroidStudio2.3/system/log/idea.log` rather big,
so I post only error:

```
ERROR - aemon.impl.PassExecutorService - Accessing invalid virtual file: file:///home/xxx/Android/Sdk/sources/android-25; original:101; found:- 
com.intellij.openapi.vfs.InvalidVirtualFileAccessException: Accessing invalid virtual file: file:///home/xxx/Android/Sdk/sources/android-25; original:101; found:-
```

directory `/home/xxx/Android/Sdk/sources/android-25` exists

Comment: can you please post the logs

Comment: @abhishek I've added logs

Answer (score 2):

Check SDK location is OK or not.

File >> Project Structure >> SDK Location >> C:\Users\You PC Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Answer (score 2):

Following points may help you to solve this error.

- Go to `File -> Invalidate Caches...`, and select "**Invalidate and Restart**" option to fix this and then `rebuild` project again.
- Make sure that your `build.gradle` file has:

  ```
  dependencies {
      compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0"
  }
  ```
- Set correct path for `SDK`.
- Synchronize project manually by clicking the `Sync Project with Gradle` Files button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @abhishek I find root of problem - `/home/xxx/Android/Sdk/sources/android-25`, so I removed SDK Platfrom -> Android 7.1.1 and installed it again.
And now Android IDE again can found `Fragment`.

Comment: Always happy to help.